# Jquery Update on Back Button

Tags: jquery, select, button, drop-down-menu, back

```
<div id="inputs" style="margin:0;"></div>

$('#addtpcs').change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();

  var targetDiv = $("#inputs").html("");
  var a=1;
  for(var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
     targetDiv.append($("<dd><label for=\"addtpcs\" class=\"label\">Additional PC "+a+"</label><input id=\"addtpcs"+a+"\" type=\"text\"/></dd>"));
    a++;
  }
});
```

I have a select box (named addtpcs) in a form that has already loaded on the page that has numbers in it (ie. 1,2,3,4, etc) in a form.  The above code works great for dynamically added input type=text boxes based upon the number chosen in the select box.  However it doesn't work so well for after you click the submit button and then use your back button.  The select box shows the number but the text inputs don't load without having to click the drop down select menu and choose and different number and then click on it again and choose the previous number.

I would like it if the back button in the browser was pushed that the value would be looked at on the form and the text boxes would appear based on the value in the select box.

In Jquery how would I check what the value is on page load and on change without writing the code twice?

Thanks,

Wayne

**Update**
I have code that checks a checkbox already on the form if the back button is selected.  I am looking for something similar for the select box.  The below code upon hitting the back button will check to see if the checkbox is checked and then if it is it will show the two hidden text boxes that are in the form.

```
$(function() {
if ($("#prevcredit").is(':checked')){
    $("#credit_amount").show();
    $("#credit_amount2").show();
}
else {
     $('#credit_amount2').val('0.00');
}
});
```

Comment: You'd have to store it in a cookie.

Comment: or change the url hash to keep track of the history

Comment: Hi BenM, really?  There is no other way to do that except for store it in a Cookie?  I know that I have one that checks the checkbox I have in the same form but that is $(function() { if ($("#prevcredit").is(':checked')).  Isn't there any way in Jquery to say hey check the value of the form?  The number is already there.  I just need to add the textboxes based upon the value already in the select box.

Comment: Oh, yes you could do that. I didn't realise it was based on a form that was already completed on page load?

Comment: If the back button of the browser is clicked, it will show the previous page, but not loading it again, therefore no onload event is fired. I would suggest to not rely on the user pressing the back button of the browser to go back to that page. Give the user a way to navigate in your application,  and populate the form as you wish, or better redirect to the caller page after the script that responds to submission finishes his job.

Comment: How would I accomplish this?  I have already tried to remove the ('#addtpcs').change and that didn't work.  If I remember reading correctly the $(function() is the short version of writing $document.ready(function() or something close to that so I shouldn't need to write document.ready in order to make it work, isn't that correct?  Goes back to my original question.  How do I use the change function and have the value checked on page load without having to type the jquery twice?

Comment: jvicab, that makes sense except how does the checkbox script work then if that is the case?  When the back button is pushed, the jquery for the checbox script is loaded and does check the checkbox and works perfectly.

Comment: I believe I have a solution.  The following code works on the back button.
$(function() {
   var selectValue = $('#addtpcs').val();
   alert(selectValue);
 });
This would indicate that I can create a function that will use the for loop and then create two different conditions and call the function with both of those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I resolved this.

**Step 1: HTML Portion of the code:**

```
<div id="inputs" style="margin:0;"></div>
```

**Step 2: Javascript Function**

Create a function in javaScript that appends to the targetDiv.  This function will take 1 argument.  This will be the value of how many boxes need to be added.

```
function displayTextBoxes(value)
{
a=1;
targetDiv = $("#inputs").html("");
for(var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
     targetDiv.append($("<dd><label for=\"addtpcs\" class=\"label\">Additional PC "+a+"</label><input id=\"addtpcs"+a+"\" type=\"text\"/></dd>"));
    a++;
  }
}
```

**Step 3: Create the JQuery function calls**

The first function looks at the value of whatever is associated with id addtpcs.  This will take care of looking at the value when the user pushes the back button in the browser.
The second looks to see if the value has changed while you are on the form.

```
$(function() {
var selectValue = $('#addtpcs').val();
displayTextBoxes(selectValue);
});

$('#addtpcs').change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  displayTextBoxes(selectedValue);
});
```